# How to Access Token for Dropbox SDK and Facebook API in same application

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I am linking my application to Facebook and different cloud services, i.e Dropbox. I am facing problem in authentication flow.

For Facebook authentication, I am using below mentioned method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options {

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                       annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}
```

For Dropbox linking, authentication is like this according to documentation.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
            // At this point you can start making API calls
        }
        return YES;
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    return NO;
}
```

How can I use authentication for Facebook and Dropbox together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do the Facebook call in the `else` of the Dropbox call.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
            // At this point you can start making API calls
        }
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                   annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
    }
}
```

Note that this uses the iOS 9+ app delegate method.